# Angular2 Window.Location.HREF UNIT Test

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript

I am trying to run a `component test` for `Angular2`, I have to check the function which invokes a call to an URL which allows a local run program to start. The function is working, however it is `breaking the unit tests`.

The unit test fails because `Some of your tests did a full page reload!`

Is there a way to capture the `window.location.href` call `obtaining the called URL` and prevent it from refreshing.